# Determine if path is remote or local

Tags: php

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => public\js\jade\runtime.js
    [1] => public\js\templates.js
    [2] => public\js\underscore.js
    [3] => public\js\underscore.string.js
    [4] => public\js\main.js
    [5] => //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
)
```

I need to determine which of those files is local or remote. i.e., only [5] is remote. Is there a method for doing this?

Comment: I think best way is to check all with `http://` and see if the result exist

Comment: @Akam: Can you elaborate on that? The last one does not start with `http://`.

Comment: `//` is not for local, and we knew that its short of `http://`

Comment: A protocol ambiguous solution (see my answer) would be better - more flexible, you won't spend two hours debugging finding out why it isn't working if you need to include an `ftp://` (or spdy if that ever gets going) path.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is your question about the **format** of the string (e.g., determine *relative* vs. *absolute* URI), or are you concerned with the **destination** (e.g., determine *local* (path or URI) vs *remote* (URI))?

Comment: @user113215: local vs remote, which is what I wrote. More examples: `C:/path/to/my/file.txt` would be local, `http://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico` would be remote.

Comment: Sorry, I guess my comment was unclear. Assuming that you are example.com, do you need to identify `http://example.com/favicon.ico` and `/favicon.ico` as local (are you concerned with absolute URIs that end up pointing to a local destination)?

Comment: @user113215: No, I'm not concerned with that case. I'm writing a tool that essentially takes a list of js files and bundles/minifies them. I'm planning on having it just bundle the 'local' files. Web-accessible ones are probably best left separate as end-users might already have them cached, or the contents might change.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url). Example:

```
function is_path_remote($path) {
    $my_host_names = array(
       'my-hostname.com',
       'www.my-hostname.com'
    );
    $host = parse_url($path, PHP_URL_HOST);
    if ($host === NULL || in_array($host, $my_host_names)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what this does with // like the example.  However, you could test if the string starts with // or do something like use the PHP stat function to validate it's a valid file path on the local system.

Comment: @LucasHolt how it is unclear? It does not care about protocol, it only checks if host is provided. As for stat, I'm not fan of introducing unnecessary disk IO operations, and it can be misleading, since `/non-existing-file.js` is local path, but functions `file_exists` will report false.

Comment: According to PHP docs, the behavior was broken prior to 5.47 for schemeless URLs (// prefix only). Stat calls would only happen if the URL did not have a protocol.  It's a fallback.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be a search for a double slash. Although it would be valid to have in a relative path, it would come after a period (any domain or IP), a GET variable (`.js?variables//`), or another path (`js/path//to.js`). The following code accounts for these.

```
foreach ($array as $path) {
    if (strpos($path, '//') >= max(strpos($path, '.'), strpos($path, '/'))) {
        #absolute!
    } else {
        #relative!
    }
}
```

Comment: `:` also indicates an absolute URI (e.g., `data:` or `mailto:`). These won't include `//`.

Comment: However, one cannot retrieve information from those kinds of URI schemes. At least, cannot retrieve any useful information in these contexts.

Comment: Depending on the reason for the classification, this might be important (e.g., if the code should process relative URIs but ignore absolute URIs). Also, I think this fails where `$path` is something like "myfile" (relative, but `if(0 >= max(0, 0))` concludes absolute).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `realpath()`. This function returns **false** on failure, e.g. if the file does not exist or is remote:

```
<?php
$paths = array(
    'public\js\jade\runtime.js',
    'public\js\templates.js',
    'public\js\underscore.js',
    'public\js\underscore.string.js',
    'public\js\main.js',
    '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'
);
foreach ($paths as $path)
    if (realpath($path))
        echo("'$path' is local and exists." . PHP_EOL);
    else
        echo("'$path' is remote or doesn't exist." . PHP_EOL);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Gave this some thought. Here's my solution:

```
function isLocal($path) {
    return preg_match('~^(\w+:)?//~', $path) === 0;
}
```

Although it will fail for `file:///path/to/my/file` (should return `true`), but I'm not sure I care about that case right now.

Comment: FWIW, it also fails for `/path/to/file`

Comment: @user113215: That returns `true`, as it should... it essentially only returns false for `//` or `xxx://`.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, I know.

I think the best way to check if a path is local or not is to simply check if it exists :)

For example:

```
if (file_exists($path)) {
        unlink($path);
    } else {
        // delete remote file

    }
```

Comment: Application will hung for a while if you check for remote/404 file.

Comment: file_exists also checks whether a URL exists and cannot be used to reliably tell if the path is local or remote.